# Subscribing event handlers in a factory

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, factory

I am writing a VB.Net application that needs to receive messages over TCP sockets, but my question really has nothing to do with sockets.  For simplicity's sake, let's say I want to create a class that processes data coming from an event of a Socket class that is part of a class library our company created.  In researching dependency injection, [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/09/06/di-and-events-constructor-subscription/) and [this one](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/09/08/di-and-events-third-party-connect/) says not to inject the Socket instance into the message processor's constructor just so the processor can subscribe to the event.  Instead, I should give my processor a public function and let the composition root create a socket and the processor, and wire the handler from the socket so it calls the public function on the processor.  That worked great at first.

But now I have a case where the sockets need to be created and disposed of dynamically.  The problem with the above technique is that the socket, the processor, and the event subscription will live for the life of the application.  I thought I could use a factory to create the processor object.  The factory would then create a socket, the processor, and subscribe the event handler.  But it only returns the processor to the client, so how does it ever get to unsubscribe the handler?  I don't want to cause leaks for failing to unsubscribe the event handler.

**Updated**

The following code is a full console application.  Hopefully I found the right balance between simplicity and explaining the issue.

```vb
Imports System.Collections.Concurrent

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        'Create a connection
        Dim ConnectionClient As New ConnectionClient(New MessageConnectionFactory)

        'Do some sending and receiving
        ConnectionClient.DoSomething()

        'Wait so the user can see results
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class DataProducedEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Property Data As Byte()
End Class

Public Class Socket
    Public Event DataProduced As EventHandler(Of DataProducedEventArgs)

    'In a real application, the event would fire when we receive data on the socket.
    'This provides a way to simulate that.
    Public Sub SimulateReceivedData(Data As Byte())
        RaiseEvent DataProduced(Me, New DataProducedEventArgs With {.Data = Data})
    End Sub

    Public Sub Send(Data As String)
        Console.WriteLine("Sending over socket: {0}", Data)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MessageProcessor
    Public Sub Consume(Data As Byte())
        Console.WriteLine("Received {0} bytes of data", Data.Length)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MessageSender
    Private _socket As Socket
    Public Sub New(socket As Socket)
        _socket = socket
    End Sub

    Public Sub Send(Message As String)
        _socket.Send(Message)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MessageConnection
    Public Property Processor As MessageProcessor
    Public Property Sender As MessageSender
End Class

Public Class ConnectionClient
    Private _Factory As MessageConnectionFactory

    Private Connections As New ConcurrentQueue(Of MessageConnection)

    Public Sub New(factory As MessageConnectionFactory)
        _Factory = factory
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoSomething()
        'Get a connection
        Dim Connection As MessageConnection = _Factory.Create

        'Do something with it
        Connection.Sender.Send("Test")

        'TODO - I could dispose of it here but that doesn't
        'remove the event handlers    
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MessageConnectionFactory
    Public Function Create() As MessageConnection
        'Create the objects
        Dim MySocket As New Socket
        Dim Connection As New MessageConnection
        Connection.Processor = New MessageProcessor
        Connection.Sender = New MessageSender(MySocket)

        'How could this handler ever get removed?
        AddHandler MySocket.DataProduced, Sub(sender, e) Connection.Processor.Consume(e.Data)

        'The client only cares about the message connection object, not the socket
        Return Connection
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]? Something that I could copy, paste, and run in a VB.NET Console App?

Comment: I've updated the code to something you can paste into a console app and run.  In a real application, there are more complex mechanisms for creating and destroying connections.  The key point is the TODO, where the event handlers should really be removed.  As it is the Socket object will live forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this work for you?

```
Public Class ConnectionClient

    Private _Factory As MessageConnectionFactory

    Public Sub New(factory As MessageConnectionFactory)
        _Factory = factory
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoSomething()
        _Factory.Using(Sub(c) c.Sender.Send("Test"))
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class MessageConnectionFactory
    Public Sub [Using](action As Action(Of MessageConnection))
        Dim MySocket As New Socket
        Dim Connection As New MessageConnection
        Connection.Processor = New MessageProcessor
        Connection.Sender = New MessageSender(MySocket)

        Dim handler = New EventHandler(Of DataProducedEventArgs)(Sub(sender, e) Connection.Processor.Consume(e.Data))
        AddHandler MySocket.DataProduced, handler
        action(Connection)
        RemoveHandler MySocket.DataProduced, handler
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: In the real system, the MessageConnection object is created or destroyed based on connections to other hardware, so it lasts longer than a single function.  I just wrote it that way to reduce the complexity of the example.  But I might be able to make this work using an Async function instead of an action, which returns a Task that completes when it's done with the connection.  Let me play with this and get back to you.

Comment: @RobL - You can make an action last as long as you like. It ends up helping to enforce a more functional style of coding.

Comment: Sure but if I don't make it Async it's going to block the caller.

Comment: @RobL - This is the first time you mentioned that you don't want to block the caller. And using an async function doesn't preclude you from using an action. In fact you can use the two together just fine.

Comment: This works great.  I did find by experimentation that most of the time I don't need this level of complexity.  The event subscriptions are kept in the socket, which is referenced only by the sender, which is referenced only by the MessageConnection object.  So to get rid of them, I only have to stop referencing the MessageConnection instance and the GC will (eventually) remove everything down to the socket, so no leaks.  But I do have one case where the socket is kept and I need to add and remove subscribers on the fly.  In that case, the above example works very well.  Thanks!

Comment: @RobL - Excellent. Do keep in mind that the GC doesn't dispose of unmanaged resources. You have to explicitly do that yourself.